# How to order items based on a column in child table in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have two tables (`FactorItems` and `Products`), my `Factoritems` table contains columns `Id, ProductId, Qty, IsBuy` and `Products` table contains columns `Id`, `Name`, .... .

I want to use code to select my product where my `Qty` column has a value (for show popular `Products` in index), and I have a foreign key from `ProductId` column in `FactorItems` table to `Id` column in the `Product` table.

And I use a virtual view model in ASP.NET MVC:

```
model.BestSellersProducts = blProduct.Select().OrderByDescending(p => p.FactorItems.Select(c => c.Qty)).take(3);
```

I get this error from my index in `foreach`:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: DbSortClause expressions must have a type that is order comparable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DbSortClause expressions must have a type that is order comparable parameter Name :Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738887/dbsortclause-expressions-must-have-a-type-that-is-order-comparable-parameter-nam)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Considering your `Product` and `FactorItem` have `One-to-Zero-or-One` relationship as follows:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public FactorItem FactorItem { get; set; }
}

public class FactorItem
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Product")]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
    public bool IsBuy { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

Then your query to get top 3 sold products should be as be follows:

```
List<Product> products = dbContext.Products.OrderByDescending(p => p.FactorItem.Qty).Take(3).ToList();
```

### Considering your `Product` and `FactorItem` have `One-to-Many` relationship as follows:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FactorItem> FactorItems { get; set; }
}

public class FactorItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Product")]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
    public bool IsBuy { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

Then your query to get top 3 sold products should be as be follows:

```
var productList = dbContext.FactorItems.GroupBy(fi => new { fi.ProductId, fi.Product.Name }).Select(g => new
        {
            ProductId = g.Key.ProductId,
            ProductName = g.Key.Name,
            TotalSoldQty = g.Sum(x => x.Qty)
        }).OrderByDescending(x => x.TotalSoldQty).ToList();
```